# Combine data from multiple excel spreadsheets

Tags: excel

I have been collecting data for a 3-stage research project. Unfortunately, the data for each stage is stored in a different page of a spreadsheet (not my doing, and there isn't anything I can do about it). However, to analyze the data, I need to combine all of the data into a single spreadsheet page, adding the information from the 2nd and 3rd page of the spreadsheet to the end of the appropriate row in the first sheet.  That is, I need to add a participant's responses in stage 2 and 3 to their responses in stage one.  Due to attrition in each stage, not everyone appears in each spreadsheet. Is there an easier way to combine the data, aside from sorting each page alphabetically, matching the names up, and then copying and pasting the rows from the second and third spreadsheet into the first?

Comment: How are participants identified? Do they all have unique ids, or names you can rely upon being consistently spelled? Do you want to combine the results into different columns such as B for sheet 1, C for sheet2, D for sheet3?

Comment: In each stage of the data collection, names, email addresses, and 5-digit PIN numbers were collected.  There were some misspellings or mistakes, but for the most part, that information is identical for each of the 3 stages.  Yes, I want to combine the results into new columns.  For example, there are 112 columns in the first page, 50 in the second, and 50 in the third, and I would like the combined spreadsheet to have 212 columns. I figure I can easily delete the redundant columns (name, eamil, PIN #) once the file has been combined.

Comment: are you comfortable doing this with vba or would you prefer formulas. @Eddie is right that pivot tables will let you consolidate also.

Comment: I'm sure this is a stupid question: What is VBA?  I usually use formulas, and have used pivot tables in the past for other things, but not for data consolidation.

Comment: Visual Basic for Applications and would mean creating a macro instead. Which could be done as well

Comment: Ah.  Well, the lookup function worked great.  However, if you have a VBA solution in mind, that would be very helpful as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are more comfortable with formulas.
Make sure the PIN# is in the far left column of each sheet, (assuming they are unique and not misspelled)
I assume you have headers in row 1 and this formula reflects 1000 rows and $AX$1000 must be adjusted depending upon how many are in Sheet2 & Sheet3.

A2 is your first record. Make sure the $ signs are the way they are in these examples 
Starting at Sheet1 at column 113 (which is DI) type

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$AX$1000,COLUMN()-111,FALSE)
```

drag the formula over to Column 162 (FF)

Do the same for the columns in Sheet3. Starting at Column 163 (which is FG)

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet3!$A$2:$AX$1000,COLUMN()-161,FALSE)
```

drag the formula over to Column 212 (HD)

Answer (score 0):

PivotTable.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/pivottable-reports-101-HA001034632.aspx